¿Como puedo saber que me provoca este error? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') at HTMLDocument.onDocumentLoad
estoy intentando grabar datos en una tabla de sql y no hago mas que recibir un error y no se muy bien que puede ser. El error consiste en que al pulsar el boton de grabar direccion me esta diciendo que la pagina no existe. Al mirar en el navegador me devuelve este error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
at HTMLDocument.onDocumentLoad
El Html que estoy usando seria el siguiente:
@page
@model WebApiPrenta.Pages.CreateAddressModel

<h2>Crear Nueva Dirección</h2>

<form method="post" id="createAddressForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address.Id" class="control-label">Id</label>
        <input asp-for="Address.Id" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Address.Id" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address.Name" class="control-label">Nombre</label>
        <input asp-for="Address.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Address.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address.Street" class="control-label">Calle</label>
        <input asp-for="Address.Street" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Address.Street" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address.Number" class="control-label">Número</label>
        <input asp-for="Address.Number" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Address.Number" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address.City" class="control-label">Ciudad</label>
        <input asp-for="Address.City" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Address.City" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address.Country" class="control-label">País</label>
        <input asp-for="Address.Country" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Address.Country" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address.PostalCode" class="control-label">Código Postal</label>
        <input asp-for="Address.PostalCode" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Address.PostalCode" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address.Active" class="control-label">Activo</label>
        <input asp-for="Address.Active" type="checkbox" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address.Def" class="control-label">Predeterminado</label>
        <input asp-for="Address.Def" type="checkbox" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Crear Dirección</button>
    <a asp-page="/IndexAddress" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancelar</a>
</form>



@section Scripts {
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            console.log('El script se está ejecutando'); // Verifica si el script se ejecuta
            const form = document.getElementById('createAddressForm');
            if (form) {
                form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                    console.log('Formulario enviado');
                });
            } else {
                console.error('Formulario no encontrado: #createAddressForm');
            }
        });
    </script>
}


el cs que tiene por detras seria este, es una aplicacion en c#:

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using WebApiPrenta.Data;
using WebApiPrenta.Models;

namespace WebApiPrenta.Pages
{
    public class CreateAddressModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        [BindProperty]
        public AddressViewModel Address { get; set; }

        public CreateAddressModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            Address = new AddressViewModel();
        }

        //public void OnGet()
        //{
        //    // Se puede inicializar algo si es necesario
        //}

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }


        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            var newAddress = new Address
            {
                Id = Address.Id,
                Name = Address.Name,
                Street = Address.Street,
                Number = Address.Number,
                Rest = Address.Rest,
                City = Address.City,
                Country = Address.Country,
                PostalCode = Address.PostalCode,
                Active = Address.Active,
                Def = Address.Def
            };

            _context.Address.Add(newAddress);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("/Index"); // Redirige a la lista de direcciones
        }
    }
}


el viewmodel seria este
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApiPrenta.Models
{
    public class AddressViewModel
    {

        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Street { get; set; }

        public int? Number { get; set; }
        public string Rest { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Range(0, 99999)] // Asumiendo que el código postal es un número de 5 dígitos
        public int? PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Def { get; set; }
    }
}

y el controlador seria este
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApiPrenta.Data;

namespace WebApiPrenta.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AddressesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public AddressesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Addresses
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Address>>> GetAddresses()
        {
            return await _context.Address.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Addresses/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Address>> GetAddress(int id)
        {
            var address = await _context.Address.FindAsync(id);

            if (address == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return address;
        }

        // POST: api/Addresses
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Address>> PostAddress(Address address)
        {
            _context.Address.Add(address);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetAddress), new { id = address.Id }, address);
        }

        // PUT: api/Addresses/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutAddress(int id, Address address)
        {
            if (id != address.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(address).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!AddressExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // DELETE: api/Addresses/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAddress(int id)
        {
            var address = await _context.Address.FindAsync(id);
            if (address == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Address.Remove(address);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        private bool AddressExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Address.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}

Por lo que he visto el metodo onpostasync no se llega a llamar.
Donde puede estar el error? que es lo que no esta pudiendo seleccionar?

El error es de un código javascript que no estas mostrando en tu pregunta

consejo, pon en chatgpt "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') at HTMLDocument.onDocumentLoad"

ya he probado con chatgpt y no me ha aclarado nada

No he sido capaz de ver el error de javascript ni con las herramientas de f12

@RobertoD En algún lado tienes algo como elemento.classList donde elemento es null. En el código javascript que has puesto no aparece una llamada a classList, entonces te insisto: Tu error está en un código que no estas mostrando en tu pregunta y como no tenemos poderes de adivinación, es imposible brindar una respuesta a tu pregunta

Hola @Yussef en primer lugar agradecerte el tiempo que te has tomado en contestarme. Evidentemente al leer el error ya habia buscado por toda la aplicación classlist, pero sin exito, no uso ninguna libreria externa de javascript y el unico javascript que habia usado aparece en el ejemplo que he puesto en la parte del cshtml. No espero que se usen dotea adivinatorias para ilustrarme donde he cometido el error, lo unico que esperaba era que alguien que sepa mas que yo, que sera sencillo de encontrar, pudiese indicarme el fallo que habia cometido.

Ah!! y por cierto el error que me devuelve el navegador es el titulo que he puesto a la consulta

@RobertoD En la consola del navegador (donde muestra el error) hay un link (a la derecha), si lo presionas te lleva al archivo y la línea donde se produce

La direccion a la que me dirige es esta,, no me lleva a ningun fichero propio   chrome-error://chromewebdata/:2943:19
